# Authorization for a Discord bot via HTTP?

Tags: authentication, delphi, discord

Is it possible to authorize a bot in Discord through Indy's `TIdHTTP` component?

There is a great example of sending a message to a client, but it is not clear how to enter a token for a bot.

```
  params: TStringStream;
begin
  params := TStringStream.Create('{"content": "Test", "username": "testname", "avatar_url": "https://i.imgur.com/ivUiaOr.png"}', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    httpclient1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    httpclient1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36';
    httpclient1.Post('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/443763508073594880/r8Oba0ws7WeN-n57TeF6BF6CKFFjviov6XMrMVVDUY_G18zmmY7VUwZqCiAOs9nz-CyC', params);
  finally
    params.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you read Discord's [developer documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/) yet? In particular, the sections about the [HTTP API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#http-api), [OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2), and [Bot Users](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and I have done it before using the Rest Components.

You need to pass the bot token via an auth header as explained [in the discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication).

So all you need to do is add it to the IdHTTP headers before the post.

```pascal
// Use Custom auth header
httpclient1.Request.BasicAuthentication := False

// Notice the spacing after "Bot"
httpclient1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bot ' + 'TOKEN HERE');

// User Agent
httpclient1.Request.UserAgent := 'MyBot (https://example.com,25)';
```

**Using the Rest Components instead of indy**
I have made a gist for you of code that I use on a daily basis to send messages to discord. [Send Message to discord using `TRestClient`](https://gist.github.com/AdriaanBoshoff/4baefd93709e6b762add25055a20b3ba)

**IMPORTANT**

The discord bot will have to have been connected to the [websocket gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) at least once. If you have just recently created a bot application and the token has not been used to connect the bot to the gateway it will not accept any api requests until you do so.

You will also need a [user agent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#http-api) for the bot. Failing to provide one also make them reject api requests.

Comment: Sorry I can't format

Comment: `TIdHeaderList` (what `CustomHeaders` is) does not have an `AddPair()` method. But it does have an `AddValue()` method.  Oi, you can use its `Value[Name]` property instead. But you are on the right track that you need to add a custom `Authorization` header to the request. Also, be sure to set `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` to `false` if you use custom authentication

Comment: @RemyLebeau It seems that `TIdHeaderList` is just a class of `TStringList` hence why I had access to `AddPair`. I have gone ahead and fixed my answer with tested and working code.

Comment: @Diezko I have made some improvements to my answer and tested the code to make sure it works. I have also included a gist of the code that I currently use to send messages to discord.